# Suppose that 0 < a < b. Prove that $a < \sqrt{ab} < b $ and $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{1}{2}(a+b)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For part 1, I have used the NOT operator on it, giving me $a \geq \sqrt{ab} \geq b$, and then tried to prove a contradiction to the assumption. I came up with $a = b$ by transitivity, which contradicts our assumption. I'm not sure if this is right.

For part 2, I have tried proving it directly through algebra, and it didn't work, so I'm fairly certain a different proof method must be used: either contrapositive or contradiction. But that's basically as far as I can get. I can't seem to make anything logical happen via algebra.

Comment: Yes, if you assume the negation and then derive a=b then this contradicts a<b and therefore you have proved the proposition.

Comment: Thank you , the second one really has me puzzled though.

Comment: Part 1 can be done directly: $a<b$, therefore $a^2<ab$, therefore $\sqrt{a^2}<\sqrt{ab}$, and similarly for the other side.

Comment: The second part is the arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality. Note that $0 \leq (a - b)^2$, so expand the right-hand side to get the desired result.

Comment: @Addem For part 1, the negation of $\;a < \sqrt{ab} < b\;$ is $\;a \ge \sqrt{ab} \;\color{red}{\lor}\; \sqrt{ab} \ge b\;$, and from that you cannot use transitivity to conclude $\;a \ge b\;$, so there is no contradiction with $\;a \lt b\;$...

Comment: I am truly, truly curious how one *comes* across a post that is over three years old and why one would think commenting on a post over three years old will do anyone any good.

Comment: @fleablood I saw it because Vikram added an answer; I commented to correct an incorrectness; and I bothered because I see math.se more as a timeless knowledge base than as a short-lived discussion forum. (Mostly I don't look at how old it is. This time I saw that only after I had added _gasp_ an additional answer. :-) )

Comment: @MarnixKlooster okay, fine.  I keep getting suckered into these old threads without realizing they are old and I get grouchy.  It's often useful on a current thread if the poster is still confused to comment an alternative explanation and side observations.  To discover the post is three years old and realizing nobody is still confused listening or thinking at these side levels is like loudly carrying on a conversation on a train only to notice your companion left three stops ago, didn't say good-by and everyone is staring at you like a crazy person. ....*oops*....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For the second part, this expression is equivalent to $4ab \leq a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ since all values are positive, and this is equivalent to $0 \leq a^2 -2ab + b^2 = (a-b)^2$ which is again equivalent to $0 \leq b-a$ since $b>a$ and is equivalent to $a\leq b$.
>
> So apparently this should be a strict inequality.

Edit:  This has some circular logic at the end.  To correct it, instead do this:

Suppose $0<a<b$. Then you get $0<b−a$ so $0<(b−a)^2=(a−b)^2=a^2−2ab+b^2$ which implies $4ab<a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$ which implies $2\sqrt{ab}<a+b$ which implies $\sqrt{ab}<(a+b)/2$.

Comment: Im not following the last part how did you conclude b > a?

Comment: I got it now thank you : )

Comment: Ah, actually, I'm now catching a bit of circularity in my logic at that point.  $0\leq (a-b)^2$ is equivalent to:  either $0\leq a-b$ or $0\leq b-a$  (or, it is equivalent to $0\leq |a-b|$).  But you should be able to just reverse these steps on the premise that $0<a<b$.  Then you get $0<b-a$ so $0<(b-a)^2 = (a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$ which implies $4ab<a^2+2ab+b^2 = (a+b)^2$ which implies $2\sqrt{ab} < a+b$ which implies $\sqrt{ab} < (a+b)/2$.

Comment: I don't see how 0 <= (a - b)^2 implies those two inequalities ? I believe I do understand that one comes from our assumption but I do not get the other one.

Comment: Well, suppose $a=8,b=4$ then $0\leq a-b$.  On the other hand, suppose $b=8,a=4$ then $0\leq b-a$.  So just because you know $0\leq (a-b)^2$ does not necessarily imply $0\leq a-b$ because you could be off by a factor of -1.

Comment: @Addem Its a lot simpler than that: $\;(a-b)^2 \geq 0\;$ since the square of _any_ number is non-negative, so also that of $\;a-b\;$.

Answer (score 1):

We seek to prove $a<\sqrt{ab}<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

We take the inequalities one at a time

Firstly, since $a<b, \sqrt{ab}>\sqrt{aa}=a$

Note that when expanding $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt
{b})^2$, which is clearly greater than zero, we obtain $a+b-2\sqrt
{a}\sqrt{b}>0$, thus $a+b>2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}>\sqrt{ab}$

Finally, since $a<b, \sqrt{ab}<\sqrt{bb}=b$

Combining these, we obtain the desired inequalities

Answer (score 0):

I would start with what you need to prove, and try to simplify it using the information you have.$%
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
%$

For part 1, we could calculate like this:
$$\calc
    \tag{1}
    a < \sqrt{ab} < b
\op\equiv\hints{square both sides of both inequalities,}\hints{no sign changes since all are positive}\hint{-- to get rid of the square root}
    a^2 < ab < b^2
\op\equiv\hints{divide left inequality by positive $\;a\;$;}\hints{divide right inequality by positive $\;b\;$;}\hint{-- this is the most direct simplification}
    a < b \;\land\; a < b
\op\equiv\hint{simplify}
    a < b
\endcalc$$
So the complex $\Ref{1}$ turns out to be *equivalent* to part of the assumption.

And for part 2:
$$\calc
    \tag{2}
    \sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{1}{2}(a+b)
\op\equiv\hints{double then square both sides of the inequality,}\hints{no sign change since both are positive}\hints{since $\;a\;$ and $\;b\;$ are positive}\hint{-- to get rid of the fraction and square root}
    4ab \leq a^2+2ab+b^2
\op\equiv\hint{simplify}
    a^2-2ab+b^2 \geq 0
\op\equiv\hint{simplify -- the simplest thing to do with this}
    (a-b)^2 \geq 0
\op\equiv\hint{always $\;x^2 \geq 0\;$}
    \true
\endcalc$$

And note that for this second part we did not need the assumption that $\;a<b\;$.